# Pythonic way to dynamically load and call modules

Tags: python, plugins

I have a working code, but I would like to know what is the proper Pythonic approach.

My goal: have a directory of "plugins" (one module per plugin), which is dynamically loaded when the program runs. All of the modules will have a function defined, which will act as an "entrypoint".

The aim is to have a script which is easily extended by some extra functionality.

What I have come up with is the following. **reporter = plugin** in this case.

```
import os
import importlib
import reporters  # Package, where plugins (reporters) will reside


def find_reporters():
    # Find all modules in directory "reporters" which look like "*_reporter.py"
    reporters = [rep.rsplit('.py', 1)[0] for rep in os.listdir('reporters') if rep.endswith('_reporter.py')]

    functions = []
    for reporter in reporters:
        module = importlib.import_module('.' + reporter, 'reporters')
        try:
            func = getattr(module, 'entry_function') # Read the entry_function if present
            functions.append(func) # Add the function to the list to be returned
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)

    return functions


def main():
    funcs = find_reporters()
    for func in funcs:
        func()  # Execute all collected functions
```

I am not too seasoned in Python, so is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Might be the right place to ask this!

Comment: Would work I guess. Though you want to think about how you will handle versioning later on. You could also use a `@register` kind of decorator, so that importing the module would automatically populate a registry of plugins.

Comment: @AbijithMg thanks! Didn't know about this page.

Comment: @spectras do you mean that each of the plugins would import the decorator from the main program, and then by using it on their functions they would be "registered"?

Comment: @MartinMelka> that's what I meant indeed. Some parts of Django work like this. Custom template tags if my memory does not fail me. Thus the main program just has to `import_module` and see what showed up in the plugin registry. It avoids the need to define a specific entry-point name, and it allows multiple extensions in the same python module, should it make sense.